# Excel 2010 VBA - Update Graph using range defined by variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet that is updating daily.  I am trying to automatically update a graph with the new data (1 row) that is added daily.

So far I have:

```
Sub UpdateGraphs()

    Dim latestRow As Integer

    Sheets("DailyJourneyProcessing").Select

    Range("A500").Select

    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
        If ActiveCell.Value <> "" Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
    Loop

    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    latestRow = ActiveCell.row

    Dim str1 As String
    Dim rng1 As Range

    str1 = "=DailyJourneyProcessing!$F$180:$F$" & latestRow
    Set rng1 = Range(str1)

    Debug.Print "Got this far..."

    Set ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range(str1)
```

I know that this looks like I simply copy the previous row but the formula's included take car of the changes in data.

The Integer / row at the moment is around 520, so I want to do:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=DailyJourneyProcessing!$F$180:$F$520"
```

Where the row number changes daily.  This is one of about 20 range updates I need to automate, but once I have solved one the others should be the same.

I have tried everything I can find online, but nothing quite worked.

At the moment, I get a run-time error 91:  Object or With block variable not set.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually no need for VBA to accomplish this. You will find the method in [this link](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/10/15/dynamic-chart-data-series/) much easier to manage and maintain than VBA code. Also, its really best not to use VBA when you don't have to!

However, so that you can see a more efficient way to code what you were trying to do, I've offered the code below. It very well may need some tweaks to fit your actual data set.

```
Sub UpdateGraphs()

    Dim wks As Worksheet, rng1 As Range
    Dim latestRow As Long ' changed to long to handle rows over 32,000 (whatever number Integer stops at)

    Set wks = Sheets("DailyJourneyProcessing")

    With wks

        latestRow = .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        str1 = "=DailyJourneyProcessing!$F$180:$F$" & latestRow

        Set rng1 = Range(str1)

        Dim myChart As Chart
        Set myChart = .ChartObjects("myChartName")

        myChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = rng1

    End With

End Sub
```